# pivottable.js display introduces NULL values that don't exist in the source pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, jupyter, pivottable.js

I believe I'm using pivottable.js (in a Jupyter notebook) correctly, but please let me know if that's not the case.

In this example, I'm creating almost the simplest pandas dataframe possible:

```
test_data = DataFrame([['a', 'b'], ['b', 'a']], columns=['var1', 'var2'])

test_data
```

Dataframe:

```
    var1 var2
0     a     b
1     b     a
```

When I display this in pivottable.js

```
pivot_ui(test_data)
```

The table shows that `var1` and `var2` both have 3 NULL values, and a total count of 5 records.

[pivottable.js image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9y4Q.jpg)

Is this expected behavior for my usage shown above?  More than happy to be told I'm an idiot and I'm using pivottable.js incorrectly.  :)

If this is unexpected behavior, I can provide further information about my system configuration.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of this library... Can you file a Github issue here please? https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/jupyter_pivottablejs/issues

Comment: I'm not able to replicate this locally, so I'll need more info about your system, but it's much easier to communicate via Github :)

Comment: Nicolas, thanks for your response!  I filed a Github issue as you suggested.  Did my usage of pivottablejs look correct?  Thanks!

Comment: Also, is there an alternative data representation I can use as input that's not a pandas dataframe?  I couldn't tell from the jupyter_pivottablejs documentation.  Happy to plug in some other data representation if that avoids this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not yet solved in the code for Windows.

Here is the corresponding Github issue:
https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/jupyter_pivottablejs/issues/52

They provide a work around that worked for me:

```
def pivot_ui(df, **kwargs):
    import pivottablejs
    class _DataFrame(pd.DataFrame):
        def to_csv(self, **kwargs):
            return super().to_csv(**kwargs).replace("\r\n", "\n")
    return pivottablejs.pivot_ui(_DataFrame(df), **kwargs)
```